# How to sort this javascript array in descending order by nested values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How would I sort the following array so that it is in order of 5, 7, 6 due to the values of 101, 100, & 99 desired to be in descending order?

```
[
   [
      "7",
      [
         "1",
         "100"
      ]
   ],
   [
      "6",
      [
         "1",
         "99"
      ]
   ],
   [
      "5",
      [
         "1",
         "101"
      ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: `array.sort((a, b) => b[1][1] - a[1][1])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use sort and select the array's value and compare it.

```js
var data = [
   [
      "7",
      [
         "1",
         "100"
      ]
   ],
   [
      "6",
      [
         "1",
         "99"
      ]
   ],
   [
      "5",
      [
         "1",
         "101"
      ]
   ]
];

data.sort(function (a,b) {
  return +b[1][1] - +a[1][1];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Also the unary `+` is not necessary, they're already coerced by subtraction.

Comment: Or `b - a` for the other direction :)